# The problem of merging an array and a map when changing the channels permissions

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, discord, discord.js

my problem is with discord.js.

I've been working on a function `interaction.channel.permissionOverwrites.cache` that enables me to call all roles and members within a function `map`.

I created a new array to store the data that was called from the 'map' function to store the data by `puh`.

I had a problem that the data could not be executed when sent by the `interaction.channel.permissionOverwrites.set` function

> **interaction.channel.permissionOverwrites.cache:**
> [image: interaction.channel.permissionOverwrites.cache:]

> **array:ArrayPermission:**
> [image: array:ArrayPermission:]

> **The result of the problem is via the following picture as it appears to you**
> [image]

```
        ArrayPermission = [];
        interaction.channel.permissionOverwrites.cache.filter((f) => (user != 0 ? user.id : interaction.guild.roles.everyone.id ) != f.id).map((x) => ArrayPermission.push(
            {
                "PermissionOverwrites":{
                    "id":x.id,
                    "deny":x.deny.bitfield,
                    "allow":x.allow.bitfield
                }
            }
        ))
        ArrayPermission.push({"PermissionOverwrites":{ "id":(user != 0 ? user.id : interaction.guild.roles.everyone.id ), [status]:value }})

        interaction.channel.permissionOverwrites.set(ArrayPermission)
```

I expected the code to run without any problems

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
"PermissionOverwrites":{
  "id":x.id,
  "deny":[x.deny.bitfield],
  "allow":[x.allow.bitfield]
}
```

Deny and allow are arrays